# Why when I try to add an object to a list it gives me an error?

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem! I start with:

```
Dim variables As List(Of Decimal)
```

Then:

```
variables.Add(cur)
            ListBox2.Items.Add(TextBox2.Text)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox2.Text & " = " & TextBox3.Text)
```

It gives me an error:System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

variables was Nothing.

How can I fix that?

Comment: In which line is the exception thrown?

Comment: @marsh-wiggle 634

Comment: Nice :) In which of the lines you posted is it thrown. In the first or the second?

Comment: @marsh-wiggle in the second variables.add(cur)

Comment: Whan you set a breakpoint on the line, what does the debugger show for `variables`?

Comment: @marsh-wiggle System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=TCalc
  StackTrace:
   at TCalc.Form1.Button25_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\TIPDYT\source\repos\TCalc\TCalc\Form1.vb:line 635

Comment: This is the exception after the line is proceeded. Set the debugger breakpoint before the line and check what `variables` is. It is most likely not defined. (== Nothing). Correct? You have to initialize it.

Comment: @marsh-wiggle I found the solution. I forgot to put a `new` where the list is being created

Comment: If you have solved your own problem then either post an answer and accept it or delete the question. Don't force us to open the question, read it and read all the comments to find out that you don't need help any more.

Comment: @TIPD Do you think we can use telepathy to glean which line is line 634?

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: What is cur????

Answer (score 0):

I think this should fix it:

```
Dim variables As New List(Of Decimal)
```